# How To Show Program's Tabs In The Taskbar Like IE

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, taskbar, windows-api-code-pack

Windows 7 and 8 can show multiple tabs in the task bar preview.

some programs like IE, FireFox and ... can show all internal tabs in the task bar.

[FireFox Multiple Tabs In the task bar preview sample.](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?hku1azcyzjo4kn7)

I want to create a WPF program that can use this ability.I know it able with windows API Code Pack But i haven't any sample for this.

some body can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is about Windows 7 but my guess is that it's quite the same for Win8. 
Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee624070.aspx

Comment: Please avoid [link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The answer by reinder contains a link that redirects successfully to an article called ["The Taskbar"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179(v=vs.85).aspx) in a group of articles called "Extending the Desktop" on the MSDN site. Within that article there is a section called "Modifying the Taskbar" with a link to the [`ITaskbarList` COM Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652(v=vs.85).aspx). That interface is said to be implemented by some object that answers to `CLSID_TaskbarList`. So this is some stuff you can search for to get the rest of the details: `ITaskbarList`, `CLSID_TaskbarList`.

As I write this there are also some informative articles showing up under "Related" here.